# asp.net in using jquery ajax with PageMethod,validation not wotkinh

Tags: asp.net-ajax

well,im using jquery ajax with PageMethod for submitting the form but my form has a asp.net validators,ajax and returning values from pageMethod is fine but,the validators not working any more,here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
        $("#Label1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

                    $("#Label2").text(msg.d.b);
                    if (!msg.d.b) {
                        $("#Label1").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

and the code behind is something like this

```
 [WebMethod]
public static object GetDate()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ad;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";
    string query="insert into test(name,family) values('mehdi','jabbari')";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return new{

       b=false
    };
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Client validation in asp.net is called when you are trying to submit for in regular way. When you do an ajax submit validation is not called automatically and you must do that manually before ajax call is started:

```
      $("#Label1").click(function () {
          if(Page_ClientValidate()) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
                   data: "{}",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (msg) {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

                        $("#Label2").text(msg.d.b);
                        if (!msg.d.b) {
                            $("#Label1").hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

[Page_ClientValidate](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/13/using-asp-net-validation-from-client-code.aspx) (link is first I found which seems to me like useful one) is a function of ASP.NET which will validate a page. You may pass validation group as parameter: `Page_ClientValidate('validation_group_name')` to validate only a group of controls with specified validation group set.